# Listbox.List(i) error - Method or Data Member not Found

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox

I'm trying to use a multi-select listbox so users can select cleaning tasks they have completed and mark them as done.  While looping through the list I want to see if the item is selected and create a record if so.  When I try to use the `.List` method to return the data from a specific row, I keep getting the method not found error.

I originally did not have the forms 2.0 library loaded so I thought that was the issue, but that did not resolve the problem. I've also compacted and repaired thinking it might just be an odd fluke, but that did not help either.

```
'loop through values in listbox since its a multi-select
For i = 0 To listCleaningTasks.ListCount - 1
    If listCleaningTasks.Selected(i) Then
    'add entry to cleaning log
        Set rsCleaning = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM cleaning_log;")
        With rsCleaning
            .AddNew
            .Fields("cleaning_task_id") = Form_frmCleaning.listCleaningTasks.List(i)
            .Fields("employee_id") = Me.cmbUser
            .Fields("cleanroom_id") = Me.cmbCleanroom
            .Fields("cleaning_time") = Now()
            .Update
            .Close
        End With
    End If
Next i
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post code, not a picture of your code.

Comment: Please do not ever post pictures of code. This makes it not only hard to read, but impossible for us to copy it to create a test file and debugging/trying solutions. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58805777/listbox-listi-error-method-or-data-member-not-found#) your question and paste in your actual code, using ` tags to format it.

Comment: Also to answer your question, the `.list` part is redundant entirely. `.listCleaningTasks` is a direct reference to your list, so `.listCleaningTasks(i)` will be a direct reference to whichever member of that list.

Comment: Access forms are document modules (same as workbook/worksheet modules in Excel), they have absolutely nothing to do with the MSForms library.

Comment: I tried Plutian's suggestion about .listCleaningTasks(i) and got a type mismatch error.  June7's suggestion below of using .ItemData instead of .List worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.listCleaningTasks.ItemData(r)` to pull bound column value from row specified by index.
Use `.listCleaningTasks.Column(c, r)` to pull value specified by column and row indices.

Open and close recordset only one time, outside loop.

Really just need to loop through selected items, not the entire list.

```
    Dim varItem As Variant
    If Me.listCleaningTasks.ItemsSelected.Count <> 0 Then
        Set rsCleaning = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM cleaning_log")
        With rsCleaning
        For Each varItem In Me.listCleaningTasks.ItemsSelected
            `your code to create record
            ... 
            .Fields("cleaning_task_ID") = Me.listCleaningTasks.ItemData(varItem)
            ... 
        Next
        .Close
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "No items selected.", vbInformation
    End If
```

Comment: Thank you!  .ItemData was the missing method that I was searching for.  This worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the solution of June7 is correct. If you need to store the selected items and then later recall and re-select the list box items, consider to get the selected items comma delimited using this function

```
Public Function GetSelectedItems(combo As ListBox) As String
    Dim result As String, varItem As Variant        
    For Each varItem In combo.ItemsSelected
        result = result & "," & combo.ItemData(varItem)
    Next        
    GetSelectedItems = Mid(result, 2)
End Function
```

Store it into one column of a table and after reading it back pass it to this sub:

```
Public Sub CreateComboBoxSelections(combo As ListBox, selections As String)
Dim N As Integer, i As Integer
Dim selectionsArray() As String
selectionsArray = Split(selections, ",")
    For i = LBound(selectionsArray) To UBound(selectionsArray)
        With combo
            For N = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
               If .ItemData(N) = selectionsArray(i) Then
                    .Selected(N) = True
                    Exit For
               End If
            Next N
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

This will select items in your ListBox as they were before.

Comment: And again, no need to loop through all items of listbox to build CSV or save each selected item, just loop through ItemsSelected. No need to save a CSV - listbox  selection can be rebuilt from a recordset of saved records. Either way, setting selection does require looping through all items as you show.